# Search string in all scripts (including Container-bound files) in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to search for a string in all my files (scripts and container-bound files, like scripts in spreadsheets or docs) and I am not having luck with that.

The following code successfully retrieves the scripts that have the text 'var':

```
function myFunction() {
  var fs = DriveApp.getRootFolder().searchFiles('fullText contains "var"');
while (fs.hasNext()) {
    var file = fs.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }
}
```

But it does not retrieve the scripts in container-bound files. Even if I try inside container-bound files, it still lists all standalone scripts with the text, but not container-bound ones (not even the one I am executing it from).

Any clue? Thanks!!

Comment: I think that the reason of your issue might be due to this. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037 Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, the container-bound script cannot be still directly searched by Drive API and Apps Script API.

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike ! The scripts that I want to find are connecting to an external DB, so they are asking for permissions before running. Do you know a way of listing permissions for the files? Maybe this way I can list all files that I want, not just scripts. The only permissions I get to see are user read/write permissions using the Drive API, not the grants that the user gives.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about ` Do you know a way of listing permissions for the files? Maybe this way I can list all files that I want, not just scripts.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 1):

### Consideration

Container-bound Script Projects are not indexed by the Google Drive API. It's not possible to retrieve the Project file using the FileID/ProjectID.

### This feature has been requested

This feature is currently unavailable, but it has been requested. Feel free to star the [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111149037) to increase its visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all sorts of ways to get the container-bound script IDs programmatically from container IDs (but now I know it's not possible currently, as documented elsewhere and issue tracked)

The closest I came to trying to find strings within all of my stand-alone or container-bound scripts is via the **native UI search bar on https://script.google.com**.

It's not perfect, but better than browsing all the containers one by one in Drive! And so far I don't think it has missed any script. YMMV.